# accessing iPhone compass with JavaScript

Tags: iphone, compass-geolocation

Know if it's possible to access the iPhone compass in Safari using JavaScript? I see [how the GPS can be accessed](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/GettingGeographicalLocations/GettingGeographicalLocations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH5-SW2), but I can't figure out the compass.

Comment: Just noticed this W3C Compass API draft published today: http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/system-info/compass.html So maybe this sort of functionality will arrive somewhat.

Comment: In iOS5 you can access the compass with webkitCompassHeading
check out [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/DeviceOrientationEvent/DeviceOrientationEvent.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/DeviceOrientationEvent/webkitCompassHeading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access that information via javascript, unless you're using something like [iPhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

At the time this was true, in iOS 5 you can use the compass heading in JS.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/deviceorientationevent/1804777-webkitcompassheading

Comment: this answer is no longer true, iOS 4.2 provides webkitCompassHeading, look at awoodland's answer

Answer (score 4):

On **iOS**, you can retrieve the **compass** value like this.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
    console.log( e.webkitCompassHeading );
}, false);
```

For more informations, read the [Apple DeviceOrientationEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/) documentation.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For Android it works auto, for iOS it needs to be clicked to start it.
Here's a part of code you can use for that

```
startBtn.addEventListener("click", startCompass);

function startCompass() {
  if (isIOS) {
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response === "granted") {
          window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handler, true);
        } else {
          alert("has to be allowed!");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", handler, true);
  }
}

function handler(e) {
  const degree = e.webkitCompassHeading || Math.abs(e.alpha - 360);
}
```

Full tutorial is here, try demo also
https://dev.to/orkhanjafarovr/real-compass-on-mobile-browsers-with-javascript-3emi

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use LeafletJS with this plugin 
https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-compass

very simple to use with events and methods.

You can try a demo here:
https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-compass/