# Access smart phone's sensors data in a browser?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I programmatically access a smartphone's sensors through the browser and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893326/can-i-programmatically-access-a-smartphones-sensors-through-the-browser-and-jav)

Is it possible to get access to a smartphone's sensors data in a browser. i.e. Can we get data from a phone's Gyroscope at the browser level? Say in JS?

Answer (score 2):

I recently discovered an abstract describing this feature as harmful because you can log the users' key strokes - it's called TouchLogger.

> W3C has recently published DeviceOrientation Event Specification to
>   allow web applications to access accelerometer and gyroscope sensors
>   through Javascript Javascript, which both Android 3.0 and iOS4.2 will
>   support. This suggests that our motion-based key logger can be
>   delivered from a website, without requiring the user to install any
>   application.

Source: http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~hchen/paper/hotsec11.pdf

So yes, the phone's Gyroscope must somehow be accessed in JS.

Answer (score 0):

No, unless the browser is a custom app which provides this data through a JavaScript interface (ie on iPhone, the iPhone app uses [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) to tell Safari that a sensor updated each time it does)